# PHP email working correctly but not actually being received by the user

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Once the form is submitted with correct information a message will appear informing the user that the email was sent. however for some reason the email is not being received by the user.

I have already checked online but to no avail. Can someone kindly help me solve this issue?

The following is the code for both the HTML form and PHP.

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea class="form-control inputStyle" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="6" required></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>                

                       <!-- Contacting Support Team -->
                       <?php

                            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                                $email = $_POST['email'];
                                $name = $_POST['name'];
                                $comment = $_POST['comments'];

                                if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($comment)){

                                    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

                                    $mail = new PHPMailer;

                                    $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';                 // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                                    $mail->Port = 465;
                                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                                    $mail->Username = '*****';                 // SMTP username
                                    $mail->Password = '*****';                           // SMTP password
                                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

                                    $mail->From = '*****';;
                                    $mail->addAddress($email);                            // Name is optional
                                    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

                                    $mail->Subject = 'Test';
                                    $mail->Body    = '$comment';
                                    $mail->AltBody = '$comment';

                                    if(!$mail->send()) {
                                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id="myAlert">
                                        <a href="#"class="close">&times;</a>
                                        <strong> Email not sent </strong> Something went wrong.
                                        </div>';

                                        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                                    } else {
                                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="myAlert">
                                        <a href="#"class="close">&times;</a>
                                        <strong> Email sent!</strong> We will contact you as soon as possible.
                                        </div>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sending an email doesn't guarantee receipt of an email. The code could be sending it, but maybe the mailserver you set isn't forwarding it on, or the remote mailserver rejected it, or the user's spam filter got rid of it or put it in their junk folder. Could be any number of reasons. All you can do from your side is check the mail is correctly addressed and formed, and that you're definitely authenticating correctly with your mailserver. FWIW I've never seen a mail host referenced like `ssl://...` before. Did some documentation tell you to do it like that?

Comment: Hi ADyson, yes actually. I was searching for quite awhile on the internet and found some code snippets like such. Should I try changing it?

Comment: Firstly try adding the `$mail->isSMTP();` command to ensure PHPMailer knows to use SMTP. Also set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` to get verbose output from PHPMailer. If that doesn't work, then just trying losing the `ssl://` part, to humour me.

Comment: just noticed as well that you're setting `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`, but port 465 is the Gmail SSL port. 587 is the TLS port. So either switch the port, or change to using `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`.

Comment: Seems like that was the problem. You've been a lot of help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

but port 465 is the Gmail SSL port. 587 is the TLS port. So either switch the port, or change to using

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`